# List of bools always returns false

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

When trying to get a list of bools to map to my properties, the list always return false for all items eventhough some of them are true. In the `SQL db` those columns are setup as bit, in my code these are `booleans`.

When I run my query directly in SQL I get the desired results, but debugging the same query in VS and looking at the output, the returned values stay false. I've manually ran an update query in the db to ensure some values are true, but still they return false. In the method I already tried to clear the list before filling it up but doesn't help.

DataAccess using Dapper:

```
    public List<PromoLinesBPConditions> GetBlankPaperConditions()
    {
    using (IDbConnection connection = new 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal(_dbNameEng)))
    {
    var output = connection.Query<PromoLinesBPConditions>($"SELECT 
    Invoice_Promo, CopyInvoice_Promo, Folio_Promo, ConfLetter_Promo, 
    BQTOffer_Promo, BQTPO_Promo, Reminder_Promo, ProForma_Promo, 
    Message_Promo from RPTSET_Invoice_Parameters").ToList();
    return output;
    }
    }
```

PromoLinesBPConditions class:

```
public class PromoLinesBPConditions
{
    public bool OnBPInvoice { get; set; } 
    public bool OnBPCopyInvoice { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPFolio { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPConfLetter { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPBQTOffer { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPBQTPO { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPReminder { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPProForma { get; set; }
    public bool OnBPMessage { get; set; }
}
```

In the DetailViewModel:

```
    private void GetBlankPaperConditions()
    {
        BlankPaperConditions = _dataService.GetBlankPaperConditions();
        foreach (var item in BlankPaperConditions)
        {
            OnBPInvoice = item.OnBPInvoice;
            OnBPCopyInvoice = item.OnBPCopyInvoice;
            OnBPFolio = item.OnBPFolio;
            OnBPConfLetter = item.OnBPConfLetter;
            OnBPBQTOffer = item.OnBPBQTOffer;
            OnBPBQTPO = item.OnBPBQTPO;
            OnBPReminder = item.OnBPReminder;
            OnBPProForma = item.OnBPProForma;
            OnBPMessage = item.OnBPMessage;
        }
    }
```

In the database, `OnBPInvoice (Invoice_Promo column)` and `OnBPCopyInvoice (CopyInvoice column)` are true. I want to get the correct results back.

Comment: how the table looks, what are the data types for those columns

Comment: All those columns are of bit datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper does provide out of the box mapping like EF does(with [Column("MyColumnName")]

Meaning that the class properties must be **exactly** as they are written in the DB

Meaning that *Invoice_Promo* (as in your **SELECT** statement) must be named

`public bool Invoice_Promo{ get; set; }`

If you want to can create your custom mapper and use it like so

```
     public class MyMapper : EntityMap<MyClassName>
     {
         public MyMapper()
         {
             Map(i => i.MyPropery).ToColumn("MyCustomPropery");
         }   

     }
```

and then initialized you mapper

```
FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.AddMap(new MyMapper());
});
```

More info you can find [here](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper-fluentmap)